# Inserting value from another column based on a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to alter the values in a column, based on the values in another.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
df <- ID type no_req n
      1   C     0    4
      2   C     1    3
      3   E     6    10
```

If type = C, I want no_req = n
If type !=C, I want no_req = no_req

Desired output:

```
df2 <- ID type no_req n
       1   C     4    4
       2   C     3    3
       3   E     6    10
```

The code I have tried:

```
df2 <- df %>% if(df2$seltype == 'C'){
  mutate(no_req=n)
}else if (df2$seltype != 'C'){
  }
```

Gives me the error:

> " Error in if (.) df2$seltype == "C" else { :    argument is not
>   interpretable as logical
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In if (.) df2$seltype == "C" else { :   the condition has length > 1
>   and only the first element will be used "

I assume this is because I'm trying to assign a column instead of an individual element

**How do I get R to take the value n from the row it is looking in?**

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think the pipe works with if statements.

Comment: You need the vectorized `ifelse`. That will take care of the warning. The error comes from constructing the `if` statement wrong

Comment: `df$no_req <- ifelse(df$type == "C", df$n, df$no_req)`

Comment: dplyr chain: `df %>% mutate(no_req = ifelse(type == 'C',n,no_req))`

Comment: thanks s_t that solved my problem